# Inserting multiple files path in a single column of DB?

Tags: php, file, uploading

I am new to php. I am uploading multiple files from a form along with other inputs to database. Files complete path and name should be inserted in DB in a single column with commas. How do I do that?

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$folder = "/var/www/html/PhpProject1/";
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']);$i++)
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $folder.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
}                
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO studentrecords(name, email, mobileno,address,gender,filename) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss",$name,$email,$mobno,$address,$gender,$filename);
$stmt->execute();
echo "Successfull";
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the paths in an array, because you are uploading multiple files. So here i am using `$paths` array to store the paths.
And in the insert query i am using `implode` function to convert array to string (with comma). This way you can store all paths as a comma separated value in a single column.

This is your solution

```
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $folder = "/var/www/html/PhpProject1/";
    $paths = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']);$i++)
    {
    $paths[] = $folder.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $folder.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
    }                
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO studentrecords(name, email, mobileno,address,gender,filename) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssss",$name,$email,$mobno,$address,$gender,implode(",",$paths));
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Successfull";
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
```

Comment: Why should the OP use this "solution"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard: Agreed with your comment and updated the answer. Hope now it is understandable for OP and future visitors. Thanks :)